# SQLlite Error#2044:near 'AUTOINCEREMENT': syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

It keeps throwing error:

> Error #2044: Unhandled SQLErrorEvent:. errorID=3115, operation=execute
>   , message=Error #3115: SQL Error. , details=near 'AUTOINCEREMENT':
>   syntax error;

could anyone tell me what happened ! appreciate that!

My code:

```
private function createTable():void
{
    var sql:String="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log("+"log_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCEREMENT NOT NULL,"+
        "log_date FLOAT NULL,"+"log_content TEXT NULL)";
    var st:SQLStatement=new SQLStatement();
    st.sqlConnection=conn;
    st.text=sql;
    st.execute()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be the `AUTOINCREMENT`, not the `AUTOINCEREMENT`?

See https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: thank you,that's the problem! but it's just strings,right? Did the SQLite can recognize text itself ?

Comment: Yes.you are the man! it's yours ^^